# Анимация при скролле, с фиксацией блока

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка

Есть блок с ul>li, он находится ~ по середине на странице.
Задача такая, что по ходу скролла страницы, когда доскролим до этой секции остановить скрол, зафиксировать нужную секцию на экране и запретить возможность скролить дальше, пока не выполняться определенные действия.

Действия которые должны выполниться: (опять же) при скролле, должны подсвечиваться li (это секция steps, шаги выполнения и т.д), после того как последний li будет активный нужно разрешить скролл и перейти к обычному скролу страницы.

Что-то, не могу пока сам понять как сделать

Сорри, если описал непонятно. Задавайте вопросы, если плохо объяснил

Редко задаю вопросы, но тут что-то не могу додуматься. Я не очень силён в js. Буду благодарен за помощь.

Пы.сы. Я находил разные библиотеки, но там что-то подобное паралаксу, а мне это не сильно подходит

Comment: можете попробовать библиотеку gsap

Comment: Да вот как-то, не хочется иметь зависимость от jquery. Но может у них поискать решение можно будет